# Dataloaders Zip

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

```
dataloaders = zip(labeled_trainloader, [None] * len(labeled_trainloader))
```

What is this line of code means? I  know to zip 2 dataloaders using **zip**. But why are they adding the **length** of the dataloader .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[None] * len(labeled_trainloader)` will make a list of `None` values the same length as `labeled_trainloader`. For example, `[None] * 3` results in `[None, None, None]`.

The `zip` expression will result in each object in `labeled_trainloader` being paired with `None`.

```
labeled_trainloader = [1, 2, 3]
dataloaders = zip(labeled_trainloader, [None] * len(labeled_trainloader))

print(list(dataloaders))
```

Output:

```
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, None)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i clearly understand :)